# How to set kendo grid horizontal scrollbar Only?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo window its showing vertical and horizontal scrollbar both on grid, how i can just implement horizontal scrollbar and disable vertical , any suggetion.

code below

CONFIG.JS

```
sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                previousNext: false,
                pageSizes: false
            },
            scrollable: true,
            filterable: true,
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make scrollbar auto enabled or disabled in a Kendo grid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854938/how-to-make-scrollbar-auto-enabled-or-disabled-in-a-kendo-grid)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To remove vertical scrollbar, you have to change the CSS on the Kendo UI Grid.

Replace #GridId with your grid id.

```
...
#GridID .k-grid-header
{
   padding: 0 !important;
}

#GridID .k-grid-content
{
   overflow-y: visible;
}
...
```

Comment: but if i have other grids in application i want both vertical and horizontal it will break is'nt ?

Comment: The css above will ONLY hide the vertical-scroll for the grid with id="GridID" not the other grids.

Comment: Awesome. You're the best!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to hide the vertical scroll bar on a kendo grid you can try this.

```
$("#grid .k-grid-content").css({
    "overflow-y": "hidden"
});
```

Comment: i am using Angularjs cannot use jquery

Comment: @aftab: it doesnt make sense.  isnt it already has Jquery Lite??